# rm -rf does not delete folder contents but instead creates another empty one

Tags: linux, macos, bash, backup, rm

I'm currently writing a start script for a minecraft game server. In this script I included a backup script.

This backup script works almost perfect but instead of deleting a folders contents it just creates another one (similarilly named) and does not do anything with the targeted folder.

I'm using this command: `rm -rf "$MINECRAFT_PATH/server.log backups/*"`
This command is executed in a bash script.

The variable `$MINECRAFT_PATH` does contain the correct path. The folder created has this name: `server.log.backups` (Note the dot between `log` and `backups`). But the targeted folder has this name: `server.log backups`. This folder does exist and this is not the problem.

Comment: `rm` cannot create a directory. Double quotes prevent the wildcard expansion.

Comment: But it somehow was created! I still don't understand it!

Comment: It was probably created earlier in the scripter.

Comment: The weird thing about this is that now the folder is **not** created! (I changed the script according to the solution.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double quotes in Bash preserve most literal values of the content, so your `*` glob is passed literally to `rm`, which will try to remove a file or folder called `*`. The `$MINECRAFT_PATH` is substituted though.

What you probably want is:

```
rm -rf "$MINECRAFT_PATH/server.log backups/"*
```

This will delete the contents of the `server.log backups` folder.

Some alternatives:

- You could program your script more defensively, thus removing the `-f` option for `rm`. In that case, it would fail if the `server.log backups` folder was empty, because the glob would not be expanded and passed on literally, and there would be no file called `server.log backups/*`.
- You could simply `rm -rf` the entire folder and `mkdir -p` it afterwards.
- Or, you could also simply do a depth-first deletion of all the files and folders inside the `server.log backups` folder. `-mindepth 1` prevents the parent from being deleted:

  ```
  find "$MINECRAFT_PATH/server.log backups" -mindepth 1 -depth -delete
  ```

Comment: The folder itself got removed too!

Comment: I cannot follow, if the folder is empty, the `*` should be passed to the command directly: `mkdir foo; echo foo/*` returns `foo/*`. So `rm foo/*` should try to delete the file `*` inside `foo`, which does not exist, but doesn't return an error neither due to `-f`. But the folder `foo/` shouldn't be removed. (At least with default `bash 4` on my debian box, is this different on OSX?)

Comment: @mpy You're right that this shouldn't happen. I was wrong here. However, it also depends on the shell on what exact error is being thrown. Ideally, the script should be programmed defensively without using the `-f` option for `rm` to see if something goes wrong.

Comment: @BrainStone Could you check the update to my answer?

Comment: I double checked it. And it looks like I forgot the `*`. Now it works. Also thank you for the expanded answer!